# How does blender dealing with AMD APU when using Cycles/eevee?

Tags: gpu, cpu, blender, amd-processor

For the 3D software blender, suppose I am using AMD APU, if taking Cycles specified with CPU, would both the CPU and the GPU part of the APU be used together? Also, if taking Cylces specified with GPU, would the GPU part of the APU be used? Finally, if Eevee is specified, which can only use GPU, would the GPU part of APU be used?

Comment: Graphics drivers for AMD APUs expose the same interface as for discrete GPUs; I'd be surprised if any software treated it very differently from a separate GPU.  (Unless specifically optimized to take advantage of avoiding copying memory since the GPU shares the same DRAM as the CPU, but logically they're still mapped differently.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thanks for your comment. So... that means only the GPU part of the APU would be used for rendering if the render is specified to render in GPU and the same for when specifying CPU for render in the software.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the reason for this question is that I want to buy a new laptop. And now I am struggling in what I want.  The recent new intel CPU with small and large cores seems to be not quite kindful.  So I  switch to AMD. And I  heard that the integrated graphic card of AMD is better than that of Intel.

Comment: I don't know blender details.  Last I read, Intel's latest Xe integrated graphics are competitive with AMD, if not better.  But it's not something I was researching.  For CPU rendering, the many E-cores on Intel CPUs should do quite well; they're good throughput per power.  Of course, if a renderer can use a GPU to run faster than multiple CPU cores, that could be even better and perhaps more power-efficient.  If I were you, I'd google for some Blender benchmarks on recent AMD and Intel hardware.  And consider a laptop with a more powerful discrete GPU, as well as the integrated one.